# Is it possible to work with return types of Windows API function calls in Visual Basic? 3 questions

Tags: vba, winapi, performancecounter, kernel32

**Question 1: Why declare it as a function and not a sub?**

When calling a windows API function in Excel VBA such as

```
Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long
```

which can be called by

```
Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
getTickCount cyTicks1
```

which only sets the value of `cyTicks1` (as the argument is a pointer), why is it defined in the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff700515(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#making-workbooks-calculate-faster) as a function and not just a sub. why not write the function in VBA as

```
Private Declare Sub getTickCount Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency)
```

?

Besides, in the docs of this specific function ([QueryPerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter)) it sais

```
'Return value
'If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
'If the function fails, the return value is zero.
```

However, trying to do anything with the return value, will result in synax error:

**Question 2: Why cant the returned values of these function be used?**

A function needs a return type (in this example `As Long`) but when trying to use the return type, it will show as a red line immediately and when tried to compile or run the code give a syntax error:

```
Dim QPSresult as Long 'same type as return type of function above
QPSresult = getTickCount cyTicks1 'red line/syntax error.
```

getTickCount-function is clearly declared as function. At time of writing Visual Basic does not yet know that I am calling a kernell32 function that actually only retrieves (not returns) a value via a pointer. Do all these api/library calls only work with pointers, and thus the result-type can never be stored/used?

**Question 3: Is there a way to catch 'nonzero' values?**

```
'If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
```

When the return type of the function `As Long` is changed to `As Byte` or to `As Currency`, it does not seem to effect anything. But changing it to 'As String' lets Excel crash. I'm guessing the kernel32 returns a 'nonzero' value to VBA that is only accepted in number like datatypes. However, as of the syntax error, is there a way to store these nonzero values?

Comment: Might be worth taking a step back and reading up on [Subs and Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures). `Function`s return something. `Sub`s do not. Parentheses are used when calling functions.

Comment: Test if a number is not zero: `<> 0`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think about the parentheses. QPSresult = getTickCount(cyTicks1) does indeed work

Comment: @jonadv On a side note: Why are you declaring a function named `getTickCount()` as an alias for `QueryPerformanceCounter()`?  The Win32 API has a [`GetTickCount()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount) function. This is bound to confuse some users reading this code. What's wrong with simply calling `QueryPerformanceCounter()` as-is?

Comment: @Remy I copied the function as it is written on the linked document page, so it would be easier to CTRL+F it. I am trying to write a benchmark timer class, which would call the QPC very often and need more precision then 10 to 16 ms, so I'm afraid the GetTickCount won't suffice. It might be useful however to  finetune the QPC counts at the end of the benchmark, as having HPET on or off seems to be making quite a difference with short measurements.

Comment: My point was, why are you naming your function `getTickCount` at all? Why not get rid of the `Alias` and just call it `QueryPerformanceCounter` normally? `Private Declare Function QueryPerformanceCounter Lib "kernel32" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long ... QPSresult = QueryPerformanceCounter(cyTicks1)`

Comment: Yes, could def do that. I would not mind a shorter name though. I actually was wondering if it would make any difference in speed using Alias. Couldnt find anything by googling and running a speedtest didn't seem to make a difference (I might have to test with a more lightweight function then QPC). Do you know if it actually does make a difference while code runs? Or would it only make a difference at compile time (and the other advantage being that it would be less code to read)?

Comment: And about the name, I copy pasted the declaration function from that MS doc page. I agree getTickCount is very confusing.